# PHP search engine problem

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, search-engine

Im using Sphider as a search engine for my website, its really easy to work with but im having some major issues with localized characters.

All of my html/php pages have the charset defined as UTF-8 and the search and result page from Sphider had charset=ISO-8859-1, when I first used the Sphider "spider" to crawl my website it made all of my localized characters into some codification I dont know:

"ç" become "Ã§" and so on with "ã", "á" etc

When I created the DB in MySql I made it a utf-8_general_ci also my defenitions for the DB are :
MySQL charset:  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf-8_unicode_ci

This is a real problem because the search wont work properly, if I search "diferença" for instance, in the url it will appear as "?query=diferença&search=1" which is correct but will produce no results in the "suggested search" it will appear as "diferen�a" in case its not visible, the "ç" has become a black square with a white question mark on it.

I believe the spider might have a different working charset but I dont seem able to understand were if it is to be the case. Also being developed towards English primarily I believe its not hard to understand that it has some hiccups along the way.

Does anyone has any experience with it or what should I try to do to solve this?

What really bugging me is not understanding why I get strange symbols in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly browsing through some Sphider source code files revealed that the application works only with Latin1 charset. You should switch to some other search engine, like [Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html). You'll need to do a bit more search-related coding though. If you don't feel like doing it, and your site is public, just integrate Google search.

Comment: Thnak you, tough limited im going to keep it for now, I dont want to use google as I have no way to control the spidering or the results layout to integrate into my website. I originally looked at Lucene but it is over my head.

Comment: If you can, you could use output buffering to capture the whole page you're generating, then if it was requested by the spider, convert it to ISO-8859-1//IGNORE with iconv.

Answer (score 0):

You should have EVERYTHING in utf-8.

- The forms who edit any given page
- The physical files
- The outputted html files
- The headers
- The connection to the database
- The table definition

Miss one and you will have problems (I'm talking from personal experience)

Comment: I believe I do just the Sphider app that must not be made to use utf-8 and im having trouble adapting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the line 4 of file "header.html" in appropriate template directory to `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
2. Convert the appropriate php file in "languages" directory to UTF8.

If the above doesn't suffice, follow the answer by The Disintegrator as well.